# Creating Versatile Reusable Modules in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting to get the hang of Angular now as I build my first app, but there's something that I'm struggling to get my head around.

I'd like to create a reusable table template that can show a set of data wherever I need to. I've created a controller to fetch the data and parse it, and I've been able to implement a single instance of the table as both an ng-include and a custom directive.

The problem I'm having is when I want to display the same data multiple times in subtly different ways. For instance, maybe I want to limit the data in the table to the 1st 10 entries, or display it sorted by one property or another. Am I expected to create a completely new controller for every different instance of the table? What would be great would be if I could pass these parameters in through the view template like this:

```
<div ng-controller="tableCtrl">
    <div table-template tabLimit=5 tabOrder=['Date','Time']></div>  
    <div table-template tabLimit=20 tabOrder=['Title']></div>  
    <div table-template tabLimit=10 tabOrder=['Date','Time']></div>  
</div>
```

How would the more experience Angular coders suggest doing such a thing? I'm not feeling great about generating so many lines of code to do such subtly different variations.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to use wrap your `tabOrder` value in quotes like `tabOrder="['Date','Time']"`

Comment: See `ng-grid` implementation. It uses a `gridOptions` object to tweak setting for the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already have this implemented as directive? Check this out:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div table-template="" tab-limit="5" tab-order="Date,Time"></div>  
    <div table-template="" tab-limit="20" tab-order="Title"></div>  
    <div table-template="" tab-limit="10" tab-order="Date,Time"></div>  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('tableTemplate', function() {
    return {
        // restrict directive to attrubute "table-template"
        restrict: 'A',
        // fill the directive element with this:
        template: '{{data.limit}}, {{data.order}}',
        // create a seperate scope for every instance of this directive 
        // since each contains their own data
        scope: true,
        // fetch the values from the attributes
        controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
            $scope.data = {
                order: $attrs.tabOrder.split(','),
                limit: $attrs.tabLimit
            };
        }
    }
});
```

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/L52qT/1/)

The binding of attribute values to scope variables could also be made using the `scope` property in the directive object. But I think this version is easier to understand.

To display and sort the data, you can use `ngRepeat` with a filter. If you could provide the template you currently have, I could help you with that, too.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for. It means a module can be used universally without lots of repeated code, thank you!

It makes sense to me so I think I'll be fine hooking it up to my ng-repeats and filters. I'll try it out when I get chance and get back on here if I have any problems.